# Thymeleaf - how to auto adjust content fragment?

Tags: css, html, thymeleaf

In my Spring MVC + Thymeleaf application, I have a default fragment that mounts the page. It is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head th:include="fragments/common :: commonFragment">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link rel="shortcut-icon" th:href="@{/assets/img/favicon.png}"  type="image/x-icon" />
<title th:text="#{app.name}"> </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:id="defaultFragment" th:fragment="defaultFragment">
        <div th:replace="fragments/header :: headerFragment"></div>
        <div class="main-container container-fluid">
            <div class="page-container">
                <div th:replace="fragments/sidebar :: sidebarFragment"></div>
                <div class="page-content">
                    <div class="page-body">
                        <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footerFragment"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Some pages, specially those with very wide tables overspan the width of the visible area and not only looks bad, you have to move the browser "view port" with arrow keys. I'd like the content fragment to be auto adjustable.

How to to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `overflow` property to "hide" the overflowing content. Seet the `width` and `overflow` property of the element.

```css
.page-body {
  width:    800px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* OR
  overflow: scroll; */
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
  <div class="page-body">
    <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It has to work. Maybe some other CSS rules are overwriting this ones. See if the new rules are being applied in the DevTools.

Comment: It indeed hasn't been applied. But when I tried `<div class="page-body" style="width: 800px">` it displayed the page ending a bit more than half way starting from the left side of the screen. It felt like the div was starting in the left margin of the browser, not where the `<div th:replace="fragments/sidebar :: sidebarFragment"></div>` ends.

Comment: `800px` is just an example. You'd need to figure out it yourself.

Comment: I meant that it did not auto-adjusted the `<div layout:fragment="content"></div>`.